# Test conditional statements reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to test this component. When the user searches for something and there is no result, it shows a paragraph with `data not found for your search`. I think The test by default assumes that this `p` tag doesn't exist since it is based on a condition.

```
{searchQuery && data.length === 0 && (
     <p data-testid="data-not-found">
        data not found for your search
     </p>
)}
```

This is my approach to test this:

```
it("should show data not found text when user searches and gets no result", async () => {
    AxiosInstance.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockData)

    render(<DataComponent />)
    const searchInput = screen.getByTestId("search-input")
    const mockQuery = "AQueryThatDoesn'tExistInTheData"
    fireEvent.change(searchInput, { target: { value: mockQuery } })
    const filteredData = mockData.filter((d) =>
      d.name.includes(mockQuery)
    )

    const dataNotFoundText = screen.queryByTestId("data-not-found")

    if (filteredData.length === 0 && searchInput.value === mockQuery) {
      expect(dataNotFoundText).toBeInTheDocument()
    }
  })
```

I get the following error in the terminal:

```
expect(received).toBeInTheDocument()

    received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
    Received has value: null

      178 |
      179 |     if (filteredData.length === 0 && searchInput.value === mockQuery) {
    > 180 |       expect(dataNotFoundText).toBeInTheDocument()
          |                                ^
      181 |     }
      182 |   })
      183 | })
```

How can I make this test work properly so when the user finds nothing, it runs this test properly.

Comment: Looking at the code arent you missing a quote here `const dataNotFoundText = screen.queryByTestId("data-not-found)` <- here?

Comment: Thank you, but that was not an issue. I forgot to paste it properly here.
I will edit it

Comment: can you create a reproducible demo using something like codesandbox?

Comment: Please provide the full code.